# Nexus - Nuget proxy configuration of Nexus Remote Automatically blocked and Unavailable

Tags: repository, nuget, nexus

I am trying to integrate Nexus repository OSS to manage NuGet repositories. I followed the tutorial here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvurW9XsLN0

I've added a proxy repository for https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ 
The proxy repository status says In Service- Remote Automatically blocked and Unavailable

I'm able to access Nuget packagfes via the default package source.
but with the proxy repository i'm unable to fetch packages via package manager.

I tried enabling/disabling Automatic Blocking property in nexus
replacing nuget.org with its ip address

What could be causing this problem?
Is this because of any firewall settings?
The status is same for all default proxy repositories too.
If so, how do i correct it?

Please help.
Log files are displayed below

```
WARN  [qtp22907850-51] anonymous com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nuget.passthrough.PassThroughNugetGallery - Exception attempting to contact proxied repository nuget-proxy.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RemoteStorageException: Transport error while executing GET method [repositoryId="nuget-proxy", requestPath="Search?$filter=IsLatestVersion&$orderby=DownloadCount%20desc,Id&$skip=0&$top=80&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net45'&includePrerelease=false", remoteUrl="https://191.236.146.247/api/v2/Search?$filter=IsLatestVersion&$orderby=DownloadCount%20desc,Id&$skip=0&$top=80&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net45'&includePrerelease=false"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Bad. Didn't realise i'm behind a proxy server. Once i setup the HTTP Proxy from the .pac files we usually use , the repository started functioning. :)